# Delete cookie for Mailchimp Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, popup, mailchimp

I have a wordpress website where you click on a div, and a mailchimp popup form pops up. One issue is, mailchimp stores a cookie to make sure the popup is only done once. But since I'm now doing it on a click, I want to get rid of that cookie.

This is my code:

```
var mailchimpConfig = {
        baseUrl: 'mc.us17.list-manage.com',
        uuid: '1356322e2......rest of my code',
        lid: '36776d...rest of my code'
    };

    // No edits below this line are required
    var chimpPopupLoader = document.createElement("script");
    chimpPopupLoader.src = '//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js';
    chimpPopupLoader.setAttribute('data-dojo-config', 'usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false');

    var chimpPopup = document.createElement("script");
    chimpPopup.appendChild(document.createTextNode('require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function (L) { L.start({"baseUrl": "' +  mailchimpConfig.baseUrl + '", "uuid": "' + mailchimpConfig.uuid + '", "lid": "' + mailchimpConfig.lid + '"})});'));

    jQuery(function ($) {
        document.body.appendChild(chimpPopupLoader);

        jQuery(".coming-soon").on("click", function () {
            alert("Hello");
            document.body.appendChild(chimpPopup);
            document.cookie = 'MCEvilPopupClosed=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;';
        });

    });
```

So after searching the internet, I found that everyone used this code to remove the cookie.

```
document.cookie = 'MCEvilPopupClosed=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;';
```

This issue is, it's not working for me. I've done all testing in incognito and can only get the pop up to work once.

Answer (score 1):

The cookie's name is `MCPopupClosed` rather than `MCEvilPopupClosed`. I'm not sure why, but MailChimp must have changed it at some point.

There's also another cookie called `MCPopupSubscribed`, which is set if the user subscribes instead of closing the popup with the 'X' button. If you want the popup to display even if the user has subscribed, you'll want to clear that cookie as well.

Clearing those two cookies will only make it work once after the page loads, though. I came across [this code](https://gist.github.com/scottmagdalein/259d878ad46ed6f2cdce) while looking into the issue, and it works fine if you put the `require` in the click function instead of a script tag. Doing this also prevents having to remove the script tags generated by the `appendChild` function every time the element is clicked.

So your updated code looks like this:

```
var mailchimpConfig = {
        baseUrl: 'mc.us17.list-manage.com',
        uuid: '1356322e2......rest of my code',
        lid: '36776d...rest of my code'
    };

// No edits below this line are required
var chimpPopupLoader = document.createElement("script");
chimpPopupLoader.src = '//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js';
chimpPopupLoader.setAttribute('data-dojo-config', 'usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false');

jQuery(function ($) {
    document.body.appendChild(chimpPopupLoader);

    jQuery(".coming-soon").on("click", function () {
        require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function (L) { L.start({"baseUrl": mailchimpConfig.baseUrl, "uuid": mailchimpConfig.uuid, "lid": mailchimpConfig.lid})});
        document.cookie = 'MCPopupClosed=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;';
        document.cookie = 'MCPopupSubscribed=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;';
    });

});
```

Comment: Have tried your code snippet but still not showing up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54601129/mailchimp-popup-still-not-showing-up-after-deleting-cookies

Answer (score 1):

you missed a cookie:

document.cookie = "MCEvilPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";

I've just corrected the exact same problem.

Hope this helps,
P.